# Redirection error in using two login pages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

My goal is to use two login pages that in mobile and desktop.

Mobile login page use ID and Password and original is use Email and Password.

So I made a mobile page include a simple login form that include just two buttons named as In / Out, and this form's action target is same as original Laravel Auth login route('/login') for use the login validation.

So I added below code to use another login page in Http/Auth/LoginController.

```
//Http/Auth/LoginController

public function username()
{
    if(request('id')) {
        return 'id'; // if request contains id in mobile then return it
    }
    return 'email'; // else return email
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    if(request('id')){
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|numeric',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($request->in == 'in') {
        return redirect()->route('mobiles_start', ['in' => 'in']);
    } // route('mobiles_start') is target to logic controller 
      // and after worked then return to mobile login view.

    elseif ($request->out == 'out') {
        return redirect()->route('mobiles_destroy', ['out' => 'out']);
    } // route('mobile_destroy) also.
}

public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->in == 'in' || $request->out == 'out') {
        return view('mobiles.login');
    }

    else return view('auth.login');
}
```

But problem is if login failed in mobile login page, then always redirect to original login page('auth.login') instead of mobile one.

How could I make mobile login page's redirection?

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi, So have you solution? :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to overwrite sendFailedLoginResponse in this LoginController.

Code for Laravel 5.3:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember','in','out'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }
```

Code for Laravel 5.5(similar to Wreigh's post):

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
   if ($request->in == 'in' || ) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ])->redirectTo('/login?in=in');
   } else if($request->out == 'out'){
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ])->redirectTo('/login?out=out');
   } else {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
   }
}
```

As the original sendFailedLoginResponse only redirect back with username and remember parameters, add in and out would make it work I believe.

However, the above is a fast workaround. For desktop and mobile, you should use responsive web design and use blade template to provide different parameters to the login function.

Also, I would use a better structure to identify whether it was from mobile login or the normal login page. For example, giving a variable like `is_mobile_login` would make the code more readable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your advice and your idea that use conditional statement in balde template is simple way to do. So I tried to get parameter with `$request->in` through above example code  in `login blade`, but I  couldn't, I think in this case `login.blade.php` must have default parameter for $request, so I just modified `redirectTo path` with your code.

Comment: Maybe you could use return view('auth.login')->with(['in'=>'in','out'=>'out']); in your showLoginForm(Request $request). I don't think the $request variable got sent to the render function at all. I strongly recommend you to reconstruct your login functions as rewrite this part would be a very annoying thing in the future and I can almost assure you this login function wouldn't satisfy all your needs (eg. Maybe showing the correct login status etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `sendFailedLoginResponse` from `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

Add this in your LoginController.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $validationException =  ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);

    if ($request->in == 'in' || $request->out == 'out') {
        return $validationException->redirectTo('mobile/url');
    }
    return $validationException->redirectTo('auth/url');
}
```

Take note that `redirectTo` accepts a **URL** and not a View or Route name.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the route 'mobiles_destroy' is leading to the wrong method. Check the redirect from  that method.

Comment: there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect for failed/missing authentication is defined in 
`Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

The functions that interest you are `unauthenticated()` and `invalid()`.

Based on your platform location you can override those in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` thus controlling the flow of failed auth and redirect.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but it just shown exception logs.:(